# AWS Device Farm: APPIUM_JAVA_JUNIT_TEST_PACKAGE_CLASS_FILE_MISSING_IN_TESTS_JAR

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, junit4, aws-device-farm

I am trying to upload Appium Java JUnit tests to AWS Device Farm.
I configured my pom.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
   <artifactId>acme-android-appium</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <repositories>
            <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>Experitest.repo1</id>
            <name>YourName</name>
            <url>https://cloud.experitest.com/repo/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
   <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>dummy</classesDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>test-jar</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
                     <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                     <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                     </descriptors>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
         <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- extentreports -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
         <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
         <version>2.41.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.experitest</groupId>
         <artifactId>appium</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

When I am trying to compile my code by maven (through CMD with this command: *mvn clean package -DskipTests=true*) I got some info rows including this information:

> [WARNING] /C:/Users/Adam Peretz/workspace/Sweetch/src/Utilites/CommonOps.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> [WARNING] /C:/Users/Adam Peretz/workspace/Sweetch/src/Utilites/CommonOps.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
>
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

and after it, I uploaded the "*zip-with-dependencies.zip*" file to AWS Device Farm and got this error:

> There was a problem processing your file. We could not find a class
> file within the tests JAR file. Please unzip your test package and
> then unjar the tests JAR file, verify that at least one class file is
> within the JAR file, and try again. For more information about this
> issue, please see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting-appium-java-junit.html?icmpid=docs_devicefarm_console#APPIUM_JAVA_JUNIT_TEST_PACKAGE_CLASS_FILE_MISSING_IN_TESTS_JAR).

What should I do? I really don't know what to do, I tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you put the Java files? The warning relates back to the jar file that's created by default in maven and not the *-test.jar

Device Farm uses the *-test.jar file and the error message suggests that it is empty. Are the test Java files under ./src/test/java? If not they will need to be otherwise maven will not package those class files into the *-test.jar.

Here is an example to compare with.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app

Hope that helps

James